# How to handle events produced by Osgi modules before a listener is registered to Felix Event Admin

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

I have an OSGi module `A` which produces an Event `EA` in a PostConstruct.

I have another OSGi module `B` which depends on the event `EA` to perform some operations.

But the module `B` is loaded and hence registers its event listener to `Felix Event Admin` after the module `A` has loaded and already produced the event `EA`.

So the module `B` fails after waiting for the event `EA` for a certain timeout value.

Is there a way I can access all the produced events before a listener from module `B` is registered?

I tried using `OSGiService(waitTimeout = 1000)`, but this only waits for service to become available.. but not for its methods to finish executing.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably make A listen to OSGi for loading of B and then produce event EA. If it is not possible to wait till B loads may be an eventstore is needed which stores events, which will be picked by B when it loads - but this is not straightforward. Making A listen to the framework for B's loading and then producing events is better even if it fired them already before for some other purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though Event Admin isn't really the right tool for what you're trying to do, which seems a lot more like persistent messaging than eventing.

An eventing model should either:

- Have listeners that don't care about when they join the event stream, or
- Maintain a separate event stream for each listener which starts when each listener joins
- Not start delivering events until the listeners are all available and ready

If you need to send an "event" at a particular time, but can't wait for the listener then what you want is a persistent messaging implementation (for example JMS). That way when your listener starts up it can begin processing whatever messages were queued while it was starting.